# How to alert when iPhone disconnects from iPad (same Apple ID) Hotspot?

Tags: iphone, wifi, shortcut, alert

Is it possible to have shortcut alert me when my iPhone (on limited Data) disconnects from my cellular iPad with much more data (same Apple ID) hotspot ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the Automations tab in the shortcuts app. You need to click on automations, then press the plus icon in the top right. After that, search Wi-Fi. An automation labeled "Wi-Fi" should appear. Click on it. Click on "Choose" in the "Network" bar and select the iPad hotspot's name. Then select "Network Left". Then select "Run Immediately. Press next near the top right. After that, press on New Automation. Then on add action.  Now, search up notification in the search bar near the bottom of the screen. Here, a result titled "Show Notification" will appear. Click on it. It will then be added and shown. You can the the text to something like "Wifi network Disconnected". If you want a title, click on the arrow in a blue circle on that shortcut. You can put your title there. While you are there, check that the "Play Sound" slider is on. Then click done. Your automation is now created.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I created shortcut and will post my findings after a week of testing. Kind regards

Comment: Did the answer work?